# addEventListener callback not taking new values from <select> element input

Tags: javascript, callback, addeventlistener

Trying to create a button that update the H1 number based on how many times I pressed it. And I added a select element to select the maximun number H1 can go to.
Why does it not work when I define the playRounds variable outside of the addeventlistener call back. but works when I define it in the callback.
this works:

```
const h1 = document.querySelector("h1");
const roundsToPlay = document.querySelector("select");
const button = document.querySelector("button");

let buttonPressNumber = 0;

button.addEventListener("click", () => {
    let playRounds = roundsToPlay.value
    if (buttonPressNumber < playRounds) {
        buttonPressNumber += 1;
        h1.innerText = buttonPressNumber;
    }
})
```

this Does not work:

```
const h1 = document.querySelector("h1");
const roundsToPlay = document.querySelector("select");
const button = document.querySelector("button");

let buttonPressNumber = 0;
let playRounds = roundsToPlay.value

button.addEventListener("click", () => {

    if (buttonPressNumber < playRounds) {
        buttonPressNumber += 1;
        h1.innerText = buttonPressNumber;
    }

})
```

When I define the "playRounds" varaible equals to an acutal number outside of the callback, it works too. So it shouldn't be a scope problem.
eg:
`let playRounds = 5;`

Does the callback in addEventListner not take updates from the change of value in <select> element when it's defined outside of the callback?

Comment: Once you assign a value to a variable it won't magically update when the source of the value updates. `a = 1; b = a + 1; a = 2` won't make `b` equal to `3`.

Comment: @VLAZ    Thanks for the reply! So the the first one works is becasue I selected the value before I pressed the button and the new value was defined in inside the callback. whereas in the second one the value was already defined before I pressed the button, and changing the value in select wouldn't change the value in the callback. am i getting this corerct?

Comment: Yes, in the second case once you have `playRounds` equal to, say, 4 it won't change when `roundsToPlay` changes.

Answer (score 1):

When you do `let playRounds = roundsToPlay.value`, the **value** (for instance, `"4"`) is copied from `roundsToPlay.value` to `playRounds`, but there is no ongoing connection between `roundsToPlay.value` and `playRounds` afterward. JavaScript does not have *references* to variables or object properties *(other than conceptually within the specification, but that isn't relevant to the code you write, just how the specification is written)*.

If you want the up-to-date value, you have to retrieve it in the event handler as you do in your working example.

Answer (score 0):

`playRounds` is only assigned once, so assuming the first `<option>` in your `<select>` is `1` then `playRounds` will be `1` forever as it's never updated.

Instead you need to compare `buttonPressNumber` to the current `value` of `roundsToPlay`

```
    if (buttonPressNumber < roundsToPlay.value) {
        buttonPressNumber += 1;
        h1.innerText = buttonPressNumber;
    }

})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/vzw6e9my/1/